# AdWords RateExceededError

Tags: python, google-ads-api

I'm building a helper library to call the AdWords (Google Ads) Keyword Planner API and having trouble catching RateExceededError errors when they come up.

The specific error message that I'm getting is below.

```
GoogleAdsServerFault: RateExceededError <rateName=RATE_LIMIT, rateKey=null, rateScope=ACCOUNT, retryAfterSeconds=30, errorDetails="Quota check failed: QuotaInfo{quotaGroupId=v2-kwi-webapi-global, userId=global}"> Original AdsAPI trace for debugging [
com.google.ads.api.services.common.error.ApiException: RateExceededError <rateName=RATE_LIMIT, rateKey=null, rateScope=ACCOUNT, retryAfterSeconds=30, errorDetails="Quota check failed: QuotaInfo{quotaGroupId=v2-kwi-webapi-global, userId=global}">
Underlying ApiErrors are: 
    RateExceededError <rateName=RATE_LIMIT, rateKey=null, rateScope=ACCOUNT, retryAfterSeconds=30>
```

I'm currently working with the below setup to call the API and catch errors, however exceptions are still being raised occasionally. Is there a better way I should catch these errors and just log the exceptions as warnings?

```
class AdwordsAPIException(Exception):
  pass

def call_adwords_api_client(self, selector):
  try:
    return _adwords_client.get(selector)
  except AdwordsAPIException:
    return None
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have made a custom Exception class which is never raised, to skip all exceptions try this

```
def call_adwords_api_client(self, selector):
  try:
    return _adwords_client.get(selector)
  except:
    return None
```

Also, api suggests to wait for 30 seconds before trying again. good luck.

Comment: I have the same problem and can't find any way to prevent the above mentioned error message from printing, even in a `try: ... except:` clause. After reading similar questions here and there it seems that it comes from `zeep` package, but it is far below my understandings. Any suggestions to cache the error thoroughly and prevent it from printing ?